# Characterize galois group of $K[a,b]/K$ if $a^2,b^2\in K$ but $a,b,ab\not\in K$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

We have two numbers $a$ and $b$ algebraic over a field $K$, such that $a^2,b^2\in K$ but $a,b,ab\not\in K$. I have to characterize the galois group of $K[a,b]/K$

I think that I would be done if I were able to show that $a\not\in K[b]$, because in that case the galois group would be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Am I right? How to prove that $a\not\in K[b]$, providing that it is true?

Comment: I think you cannot prove that $a \notin K[b]$: consider a field $L$ of characteristic $2$ where $L$ is non-perfect and put $K=\mathrm{Frob}(L)$. Then choosing $a \in L \setminus K$ and $b=a+1$ gives you a pair $a, b$ that satisfies the conditions above, but $a \in K[b]$.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume $K$ has characteristic not $2$?

Comment: The problem does not say it, but I think it would be reasonable.

Comment: The bad situation would be when $K(a)=K(b)$. Do you know the characterization of quadratic extensions of $K$ that comes from Kummer Theory, that $K(\sqrt u\,)=K(\sqrt w\,)$, for $u,w\in K$, if and only if $u/w$ is a square in $K$?

Comment: I am afraid I do not.